# List.Remove All not removing the negative numbers from textfile

Tags: c#, arrays, list, removeall

Here's what I want this code to do.

1. Read the textfile random.txt into a List
2. For each line of the textfile read into the list I want to determine if it is positive or negative using .RemoveAll with a lambda expression.
3. RemoveAll should remove each line containing a negative number
4. I want to display the changed list into a listbox to display.

I cannot use Linq, and I must use the ListMethod RemoveAll.

'''''

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using System.IO;

 namespace meade_13_1
 {
  public partial class Form1 : Form
 {

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    private void btnFindAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
    }

    private void btnRemoveNeg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("random.txt"))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                list.Add(Int32.Parse(line));
                
                
            }
        }
        list.RemoveAll(x => x > 0);
        listBox1.Items.Add(list);

         }
     }
 }
```

'''''

Comment: Don't do `RemoveAll` before you have finished adding all. Your code won't compile because you can't assign `reader.ReadLine` to an `int` and testing `int` against `null` makes no sense. Make `line` a `string` and then change the add to `list.Add(Int32.Parse(line));`

Comment: If this is the only code which adds to the list and you adding items sequentially, just don't add negative numbers to the list in the first place, thus you don't need to remove then afterwards. Moreover seems like you don't even need `List` according to the code. You don't do anything with this in your code

Comment: Or you can take a look at Dmitry's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71271681/8715436. This is very clean way to do the exact same things.

Comment: I cannot use Linq, I have to remove the negatives and cannot do it outside of the program. I must use RemoveAll.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want to show in the listbox and when you want to remove negative values? and where do you want to remove them from? You could try to update your questions with small ordered steps you need to achieve your task

Comment: Any reason why you can't use Linq? and what do you mean by "cannot do it outside of the program"?

Comment: This is for class, Im trying to learn without Linq because we arent learning this in class at the moment. And by outside the program you said in your first comment not to add negative numbers to the list in the first place. Which I interpreted as manually deleting the negative numbers from the file before even running the program which I am not trying to do. If you can help I would appreciate it

Comment: Please post the actual code you have. This code doesn't even compile so *obviously* it cannot be your actual code.

Comment: @Avmeade, no, I didn't mean to remove negative numbers from file. I just proposed not to add them to the list with the code (or in another words add only positive numbers) `if (number >= 0) list.Add(number)`

Comment: And your lamda expression effectively saying to remove **positive** elements, to remove negative elements it should be `list.RemoveAll(x => x < 0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't remove negative numbers simply because the lamda expression you pass to `RemoveAll` is used to filter positive numbers. For negatives it should be `x => x < 0`.

So if you need the version without Linq, I can propose two options:

1. Without list at all (just add to the listbox only positive numbers)

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("random.txt"))
{
   string line;
   while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
    if (int.TryParse(line, out int number) && number >= 0)
       listBox1.Items.Add(number);
   }
}
```

2. With list and `RemoveAll`

```
var numbers = new List<int>();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("random.txt"))
{
   string line;
   while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
     if (int.TryParse(line, out int number)
       numbers.Add(number);
   }
   numbers.RemoveAll(n => n < 0);
   foreach (int num in numbers)
     listBox1.Items.Add(num);
}
```

And by the way for this kind of task the `File.ReadLines` is more natural (because even the method name says that this does exactly what we need):

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("random.txt")
{
  if (int.TryParse(line, out int num) && num >= 0)
     listBox1.Items.Add(num);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of working with *reader*, *list* directly, I suggest *querying* with a help of *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

private void btnFindAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var items = File
    .ReadLines("random.txt")
    .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
    .Select(line => double.Parse(line)) //TODO: int.Parse if item is int
    .Where(item => item > 0); 

  foreach (var line in items) 
    listBox1.Items.Add(line);        
}
```

Here I've added `.Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))` to be on the safe side of the rode - I ignore possible empty lines

Comment: This may work as well, `var items = File
    .ReadLines("random.txt")
    .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) && int.TryParse(line, out int num) && num > 0)
    .Select(line => int.Parse(line));` essentially removing a `where`.

Comment: @Trevor Can't understand your snippet, could you please elaborate? How a string can be checked with `is` against `int`? They aren't assignable types

Comment: @E.Shcherbo responded to quickly, I was updating when you posted that :)

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but I can't use Linq for this and must use RemoveAll to remove the negative values from the textbox.

Comment: @Avmeade `must use RemoveAll to remove the negative values from the textbox` `RemoveAll` doesn't have anything to do with a `TextBox`, do you mean `ListBox`?